# ActionLink using Bootstrap 3 submenu not working, url not being called

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, actionlink

bootstrap in C# submenus not being called, the url is shown in the bottom of the browser but when clicked nothing happens. What I am doing wrong?

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse dropdown">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" role="menu">
<li role="menuitem">@Html.ActionLink("Contracts", "Index", "Contracts")</li>
<li class="dropdown-submenu" data-toggle="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
Configuration <b class="caret"></b></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
<li role="menuitem">@Html.ActionLink("Contract Type", "ContractType", 
"Configuration")</li>
 <li role="menuitem">@Html.ActionLink("Cost Type", "CostType", 
"Configuration")</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Does Page going to new ppage? If not then  Check if the action click event was prevented by jQuery in the code
else if page is redirection to the new page but there is error check if the Controller, action are exist in the shown  url

Comment: Updated Tags, Update Title for Searchable subject

Answer (score 1):

check your `ActionResult` does it match with your `.chtml` page `ActionLink`

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to Bootstrap 4.1. Now it is OK

```
 <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item @Html.IfSelected("Proposals")">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Proposal")">Proposals</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item @Html.IfSelected("Contracts")">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Contracts")">Contracts</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item @Html.IfSelected("Reporting")">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="@Url.Action("Reporting", "Home")">Reporting</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" id="navbarDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                Configuration
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="@Url.Action("Actions", "Configuration")">Actions</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="@Url.Action("ContractType", "Configuration")">Contract Type</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="@Url.Action("CostType", "Configuration")">Cost Type</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="@Url.Action("PendingOn", "Configuration")">Pending On</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="@Url.Action("Periods", "Configuration")">Periods</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="@Url.Action("Operators", "Configuration")">Operators</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="@Url.Action("SellerType", "Configuration")">Entity Type</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="@Url.Action("Status", "Configuration")">Status</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="@Url.Action("Result", "Configuration")">Results</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="@Url.Action("Vendors", "Configuration")">Vendors</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="@Url.Action("Users", "Configuration")">Users</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
```